# checkin locally works, I have no server checkin enabled, files stay in changes

Tags: git, visual-studio

I have a Visual Studio 2017 solution with 6 projects in.

I right clicked on the solution "Add Solution to Source Control".

I go to Team Explorer / Changes / Commit all. works fine

"Commit abcde123 created locally. Sync to share your changes with server.

(I don't want to share the changes with any server - I'm a solo dev).

The Changes window is still full of changes. It offers to take a Commit All again - so I press it - then it errors, I presume because it is trying to reach a server that isn't configured.

"fatal: unexpected sequence in commit output.".

The Changes window is still full.

I have changed files - but I can't see the changes I made (e.g. by right clicking and selecting "View History"). I think this may be because the checkin to server failed.

How can I set git in Visual Studio up to only work locally, not try and upload to a server and see the local checkin as having finished checking in?

(I think this has worked fine in the past with single project solutions).

Comment: Visual studio is hitting an error when attempting to commit your changes (basically doing a Git commit). It is not trying to upload changes to the server.

I work on the team responsible for these tools - could you help provide more information / help us repro this issue? Is this a public repository? If you do not mind, please follow up with me at jamill at microsoft.com. 

Thanks,

Comment: Thanks - so others can learn from this lets keep it here? It's not public just a private thing I'm doing myself. The behaviour has now stopped and I can't report it reliably but if it happens again I'll leave a comment here - thanks @jamill